# C# Joint Program

Tags: c#, inter-process-communicat

How can I write stuff on a console application I have open when someone enters or does something on a windows form? I have this admin console application and I want to pass codes through both.

I have a username string so just pretend the selected = the username

heres a little code to help understand

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
if (line == "messageall")
{
   //This will send a message to all users on windows form
}
if (line == "messageuser")
{
  //This will send a message to a certain user - messageall usernamehere
  string username = Args[1].ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Look into [Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx).

Comment: You need to setup some form of interprocess communication (using pipes, shared memory, sockets, or whatever you want)